# How to show a message in jsf page after completing DB update

Tags: database, jsf, message

I am using following code to edit value of a record. And the code is working fine.

```
<rich:popupPanel header="Edit Company Region" id="editCompanyRegionPane"
                            domElementAttachment="parent" width="230" height="115">
                            <h:form>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="editCompanyRegionGrid">
                                <h:inputHidden value="#{CompanyAdminPageModel.editCompanyRegion.companyRegionId}"
                                    id="editcompanyRegionId">
                                </h:inputHidden>
                                <h:message for="editcompanyRegionId" />
                                <h:column>                          
                                <h:outputText value="Name " />
                                <h:inputText value="#{CompanyAdminPageModel.editCompanyRegion.name}" 
                                    id="editCompanyRegionName">
                                </h:inputText>
                                <h:message for="editCompanyRegionName" />
                                </h:column>
                            </h:panelGrid>

                            <h:commandButton value="Update"
                                action="#{CompanyAdminPageModel.companyRegionUpdate}" render="table"
                                oncomplete="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity==null}) {#{rich:component('editCompanyRegionPane')}.hide();}" />
                            <h:commandButton value="Cancel"
                                onclick="#{rich:component('editCompanyRegionPane')}.hide(); return false;" />
                            </h:form>
        </rich:popupPanel>
```

I want to show a message in the same page after updating the value in database. For example: when I will click on the update button then it will call method from Bean class and then update value in the DB and after closing the popup panel it will display a message (like: updated successfully) inside the same page.

Any help please.

I used follwoing java code:

```
public String updateUser(Long usrId, String firstName, String lastName,
        String loginName, String emailAddr) {
    AllCompanyDAO aDAO = new AllCompanyDAO();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("test", new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage("Success"));
    return aDAO.userUpdate(usrId, firstName, lastName, loginName, emailAddr);

}
```

and following jsf code:

```
<div class="content container">
        <div style="padding-left:220px;">
             To see the relationships between users and regions <a href="#{appPath}/app/insertion/userRegionInfo.faces" >click here</a> <br/>
             <h:message for="test"></h:message>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can put a message to FacesContext with `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(clientId, new FacesMessage("Success"));`. And just have a `h:message` to display the message. See [FacesContext api](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#addMessage%28java.lang.String,%20javax.faces.application.FacesMessage%29)

Comment: Could you please tell me, where and how should I use that in my code?

Comment: Just put it at the end of your update listener method. If the update is successful, add the message to FacesContext. The message should display where ever you have the `h:message`

Comment: @peeskillet: I have edited my question. Please have a look on that. It is now working in the way that I actually I want. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: If I use FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage("Success")); Then it is showing success message outside of my desired panel. I need it to show within a specific div. How can I do that?

Comment: @Novis, instead of the `null` reference, use the component's id (String).

Answer (score 0):

At the end of `companyRegionUpdate()`, add :

1. A message

   `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("test", new FacesMessage("Success"));`

Where *test* is the absolute reference to the `<h:message>` **JSF** component.

1. To your `<h:commandButton>` , add Ajax support

Such as

```
<h:commandButton value="Update"  >
<a4j:support oncomplete="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity==null}) {#{rich:component('editCompanyRegionPane')}.hide();}" action="#{CompanyAdminPageModel.companyRegionUpdate}"  event="onclick" reRender="test, table" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Where *test* is the absolute reference to the `<h:message>` **JSF** component.

Instead of adding ajax support to your `<h:commandButton>`, you could simply use `<a4j:commandButton >` component which has ajax support.

Answer (score 0):

I used following code that solved my problem.
1. Used the following code in the companyRegionUpdate method in java.

```
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("test", new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage("Successful"));
```

Then used `<h:messages />` inside my desired div. `<h:messages />` is different than `<h:message />`. In my case `<h:messages />` works.

That's it. :-)